# JavaFX - Prevent FlowPane from growing horizontally in VBox

Tags: user-interface, layout, javafx, flowpane

How can I prevent the `FlowPane` layout from growing?
My `FlowPane` layout is inside a `VBox`, which has a max width and wraps its content automatically when needed (works with `TextFlow` and `HBox`), except with `FlowPane`.
So my problem is that my `FlowPane` layout won't observe its `maxWidth` property.

[image: Preview]

Also included:

```
FlowPane messagePane = new FlowPane();
messagePane.setPrefSize(VBox.USE_PREF_SIZE,VBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);
messagePane.setMaxWidth(VBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);
messagePane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

And its content:

```
Label m = new Label(messageText);
m.setFont(Font.font("Calibri", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD, 20));
m.setWrapText(true);
m.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
m.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
m.setMaxWidth(FlowPane.USE_PREF_SIZE); //Works with constants only
```

Why doesn't it work as wanted?

Comment: Do you have anything else inside the flow pane?

Comment: No, only the `Label`.

Comment: So what happens if you remove the flow pane entirely, put the label in the vbox directly, and remove `m.setMaxWidth(...)`?

Comment: It gets wrapped when it reaches the VBox' max width. Even when the Label's maxWidth property was not set.

Comment: So that is what you want, no? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think you might have misinterpreted what `USE_PREF_SIZE` means. This is a sentinel constant defined in the `Region` class. When you call `messagePane.setMaxWidth(VBox.USE_PREF_SIZE);`, that is an instruction to the message pane that basically says "to compute your maximum width, just compute your preferred width and use that value". The message pane's preferred width is to size itself to contain the width of its contents, which in this case means it computes the preferred width of the label. The preferred width of the label is computed to hold the text without wrapping.

Comment: Yes it's exactly what I want. But even when I set a constant as the FlowPane's maxWidth it won't wrap to the next line when needed. Thanks for that information.